# Django cant see file cms_apps.py

Tags: django, django-cms

Hi I have application in Django and I want do apphook by
http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/apphooks.html
So I have create file named cms_apps.py in my application directory

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class Aktualnosci(CMSApp):
    name = _('Aktualnosci')
    urls = ['aktualnosci.urls']
    app_name = 'aktualnosci'

apphook_pool.register(Aktualnosci)
```

reload the server of course and django cant see my cms_apps.py
I can write so random rubbish in my cms_apps.py and Django is silent.

[image]

Comment: can you show the structure of your directory where the file is kept

Comment: here you are... I know there is no urls.py jet but Django shoud show the error about this, but Django is silent it even  cant see cms_apps.py

Comment: go through the documentation of relaoding or installing the apphook, its clearly written what you need to do after creating the file

Comment: I have written I do everything by documentation  
http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/apphooks.html

Comment: Hello, is your app in the INSTALLED_APPS? which version of django CMS are you using?

Comment: of course i have it in settings.py - django 3.4.5 - my problem diappeard by weekend - but i didnt change anything in my code, I had this problem yet, of course its not about restart server, Django cant see my new application without the reason, and some time later it start to see new appplication

Comment: If it just appeared to fix itself it'll likely have been a pyc file issue.

Comment: So in the future, what can I do to avoid this stupid problem